# How to run a generalised least squares regression with a lag in SPSS

Tags: spss

I am trying to run a generalised least squares regression with a 2 month lag on my dependent variable in SPSS but I can't find the function for GLS.

Is this something SPSS can do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the COMPUTE command with the LAG function to create the lagged variable and give that to GLM et al.

Comment: Thank you! I'm fairly new to SPSS and statistics so I wasn't sure if the GLM function was the same as GLS.